# Can the antenna of a Wi-Fi modem pick up a cell phone's MIN or ESN?

Tags: rf

Specifically: Can the antenna of a Wi-Fi modem pick up a cell phone's broadcast of its mobile identification number (MIN) and electronic serial number (ESN)?

Generally: We are trying to determine if a Wi-Fi modem can detect any unique information from a passive (not during a call) cell phone transmission.  During its periodic outgoing "pinging" to the network, is there any information that is unique to the individual cell phone.  When it searches for an available Wi-Fi signal, is the phone transmitter sending any information unique to the phone?  We don't need to know the cell phone number, just any information that is unique to the unit.

Comment: Can the *antenna* from a wifi card theoretically be used with a proper GSM snooper to sniff information? Probably, but you'll have impedance mismatch issues. Can you use a WiFi *card* to sniff GSM traffic? No.

Answer (score 2):

If memory serves me right WiFi operates at 2.4GHz and 4.8GHz, depending on the exact standard.

Mobile phones on the other hand work in frequency bands varying locally 400-475MHz, 800-950MHz and 1600-1900MHz.

So the answer is "No" you cannot pick up cell phone transmissions with a regular WiFi modem because the frequency bands are very far apart. Apart from that, the protocols (on several layers) used to transfer data are different.

The different protocols have to do with the difference between transmission (continuous stream of data packets [the hum you hear when you use your phone near a cheap amplifier]) and communication (sending a single packet with data whenever required).

- WiFi is related to [802.11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11) standard
- GSM is related to various standards listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=GSM&action=edit&section=13).

Comment: <strike>They undoubtedly mean a gsm/cdma/lte to wifi modem.</strike> Actually, they mix terms. I have very little idea what they mean.

Comment: I read it the same way jippie did, but after reading your comment and PeterJ's answer, I think they are talking about the phone being used as a mobile hotspot. Also, [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DU8hg4FTm0g) is a cool video to watch on cell phone hacking via GSM.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the closest you'd find to a unique identifier at the Wi-Fi level would be the MAC address of the phone's Wi-Fi interface. That's not guaranteed be to unique because it can be reprogrammed although on most phones although that would require some form of 'rooting' so it's not the sort of thing a typical user would change.

The other complication is that unless the phone is setup to be operating as an access point or associated with an access point it won't be broadcasting that all the time as far as I know, but as pointed out by Passerby in a comment when the phone is set to "automatically connect to preferred networks" it will send out a probe request periodically, which would be a very common configuration.

However some of the specifics in that area may be a better question for the [IT Security](http://security.stackexchange.com) Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Wifi standard includes Probe Request Packets. A wifi device will send out a request for information from another device, in this case from a cell phone to an AP, based on your list of preferred/remembered networks. Pretty much how it tries to access an AP without scanning every single incoming packet. But a mac address should still be the only unique thing about it.

Comment: Look for "Preferred Network List" issues. Your phone or pc, with wifi on, and "automatically connect to preferred networks" will periodically (every few seconds), send out requests with the names of the APs it wants to log on to. Like a heartbeat.

Comment: @Passerby, thanks I thought it worked the other way around and the they passively listened for APs of interest so I'll update my answer. That makes a lot of sense because the few times I've played around with monitoring tools I have seen a lot of probe requests coming in.

Comment: both methods are available, and are used in combination, depending on the manufacturer. Same thing with APs not **publicly** broadcasting beacons (even though they still broadcast a different type of beacon with the information).